# Can I use an Eclipse plugin project for my own plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I want to create a plugin ability in my own project. I've looked into JSPF and JPF, but I've also notice that Eclipse has a 'plugin project'.

Is that specific to plugins for the Eclipse IDE, or can I use it for my own project as well? I have tried researching this, but everything seems to be oriented towards the former.

I want to know if Eclipse's plugin project could be helpful for what I need, and where I can find a good explanation of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse plug-in project is used to make Eclipse specific plug-ins for the Eclipse IDE.

Now, if you want, you can copy the plugin.xml and extensible classes model that Eclipse uses for Eclipse IDE plug-ins to have your own application allow plug-ins.

The Eclipse plug-in model is based on the [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/) model for building Java applications that can be extended with plug-ins.

Any plug-in architecture is going to be complicated to understand and create, because the application has to create extendable classes for nearly everything.

Comment: Yes, and I only need a plugin for one purpose (lookup UPC barcodes). Sounds like I'll be using JSPF (Java Simple Plugin Framework).